# Fetch elements referring to exactly two other elements in a single XPath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to fetch a node set containing elements that refer to exactly two other elements. I can't figure out how to do it in a single XPath expression.

My (simplified) source XML looks like this:

```
<group>
   <id>1337</id>
</group>
<group>
   <id>1338</id>
</group>
<member>
   <id>31415</id>
   <groupId>1337</groupId>
</member>
<member>
   <id>31416</id>
   <groupId>1337</groupId>
</member>
<member>
   <id>31417</id
   <groupId>1338</groupId>
</member>
```

Now, I want to select all `<group>` nodes that refer to exactly two `<member>`s, which should result in returning the group with id=1337 only. I tried the following...

```
<xsl:variable name="groupsWithTwoMembers" select="group[count(../member[id=??]) = 2]"/>
```

...and obviously at the '??' I need to insert the groupId of the group I selected at the start of the XPath expression, but I can't think of a way to get to this groupId. Can anyone out there think of one? Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. In addition to @Alejandro 's good answer, see my answer for an XPath2.0 one-liner solution. :)

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks for the thumbs-up. Your XPath2.0 solution looks good too, but unfortunately I'm stuck with XPath1.0 due to the software architecture of our project. Thanks anyway for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that predicates filters previous selected nodes with **each of those nodes as context**. So, you need to pull in the out of context reference.

This can be done with variable/parameter reference or `current()` function (results in context node for the whole XSLT instruction).

Also, in this case having cross references, it's better to use keys:

```
<xsl:key name="kMemberByGroupId" match="member" use="groupId"/>  
...
<xsl:variable name="groupsWithTwoMembers" 
              select="group[count(key('kMemberByGroupId',id)) = 2]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro! I implemented your suggestion (to use keys) and it works like a charm! You've really helped me out here, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**XPath2.0**:

```
$p/group[count(index-of($p/member/groupId, id)) eq 2]
```

where `$p` is the parent of the provided XML fragment.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Good answer. Do you realize that your descovery about `fn:index-of` usage for "getting not reapeated" it's usable for grouping without the need of `for ... in distinct-values()`?

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I am not using `distinct-values()` in this XPath expression.

Comment: @Dimitre: I meant that `$sequence[index-of($sequence,.)[2]]` gives the repeated values, but `$sequence[index-of($sequence,.)[1]]` gives the "first of a kind".

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but I am not sure which is more efficient.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right about that. The difference is semantic: `fn:distinct-values()` should be more efficient but the result is a sequence of atomic values.

Comment: @LarsH: THen you definitely havent seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133092/how-do-you-identify-duplicate-elements-in-an-xpath-2-0-sequence/287360#287360    :)

Comment: @Dimitre: whoa. Yeah, thanks for pointing out that gem. :-) (Too bad about all the spam on your blog entry!)

Comment: Really interesting approach! I'll keep the index-of function in mind; it might really help me out some day!

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0 this is not possible. In XPath 2.0 you can do the following (untested):

```
for $a in fn:distinct-values(//group/id) 
  if count(../../member[@id = $a]) = 2 then return $a
```

Comment: Besides missing right brackets, it doesn't look quite right... the `//group[...]` doesn't make sense, because the predicate doesn't use the context group except for `..`, which is the same for all groups. Instead maybe you mean `for $a in fn:distinct-values(//group/id) if count(../../member[@id = $a]) = 2 then return $a`?

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Your proposal looks correct. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the difference between the current node and context node. They are usually the same but when dealing with predicates, the context node (often represented with a  .) matches the node you are predicating against. In this situation you should use current() to access the current node rather than the context node.

Comment: As Mike Kay expresses it, `current()` returns the context node as it is "outside" the whole XPath expression. But in this situation, where the OP has `select="group[count(../member[id=??]) = 2]"`, it's not the context node outside the XPath expression that we want; it's the context node of each group (i.e. outside the outer predicate). Unfortunately XPath 1.0 has no standard way to access this "intermediate" context.