# muenchian grouping

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping, xslkey

I was wondering how this predicate([1]), is hardcoded as 1 always in the muenchian grouping. The concept was not clear for me, after a lot of search. It is explained as the current node, is compared with the 1st group returned by the key. 
Why does it always compare with the first one that a key is matched?
Also why are we giving `contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1], the =1 part?` again 1 is hardcoded. I referred the below link

http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering how this predicate([1]), is hardcoded as 1 always in
>   the muenchian grouping.

**This is simple**:

The `key()` function produces all nodes for a given group, and we want to take just one node from any group.

It isn't guaranteed that all groups will have two or more nodes in them -- some might have just one node.

This is why it is safe and convenient to take the first (and possibly the only) node from each group.

**We could equally well do the grouping taking the *last* node from each group** (but this will be less efficient):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNumByMod3" match="num"
  use=". mod 3"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "num[generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kNumByMod3', . mod 3)[last()])
      ]
  ">


  3k + <xsl:value-of select=". mod 3"/>:
<xsl:text/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kNumByMod3', . mod 3)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**produces the wanted, correctly grouped result**:

```
  3k + 2:
<num>02</num>
<num>05</num>
<num>08</num>


  3k + 0:
<num>03</num>
<num>06</num>
<num>09</num>


  3k + 1:
<num>01</num>
<num>04</num>
<num>07</num>
<num>10</num>
```

Comment: perfect. Also through some experiments found that the below three do the grouping                                                              1)contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]">2)contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[2]) = 1]">3)contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[last()]) = 1]">

Comment: Yes, the predicate is a test whether two nodes are identical (the same node). This also can be done using `generate-id()` and in XPath 2.0 is expressed with the `is` operator.

Comment: @user1004770: You are welcome. If you are interested in this topic, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133092/how-do-you-identify-duplicate-elements-in-an-xpath-2-0-sequence

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a key definition `<xsl:key name="contacts-by-surname" match="contact" use="surname"/>`, then the expression `key('contacts-by-surname', 'Doe')` gives you a node set with all `contact` elements where the `surname` is `Doe`. The expression `key('contacts-by-surname', 'Doe')[1]` gives you the first `contact` in that "group".

Now when processing all `contact` elements with `for-each` or `apply-templates` we usually want a way to identify the first `contact` element in each group. This can be achieved with `<xsl:for-each select="contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]">` or `<xsl:for-each select="contact[generate-id() = generate-id(key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1])]">`.

If your requirement is different and you for instance wanted to identify the last item in each group then you could of course use a different predicate, as in `<xsl:for-each select="contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[last()]) = 1]">` or `<xsl:for-each select="contact[generate-id() = generate-id(key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[last()])]">`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is that there are two nested loops. The outer loop selects one representative node from each group, and the inner loop selects all the nodes in that group (including the one chosen as representative). The easiest way of selecting one representative node from a group is to select the first, hence the predicate `[1]`.

Comment: @_Michael: There are *no* loops in my solution and it is still *grouping*. I think that for XSLT 3.0 we can still provide a *grouping function*, that eliminates the most obvious drawback of `xsl:for-each-group` -- the lack of composability..