# Find duplicate sibling with xpath

Tags: xpath, duplicates, xpath-2.0, siblings

How to find only nodes with at least a similar/equal sibling node using Xpath?

For example:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <node>...</node>
    <node_unique>...</node_unique>
    <node>...</node>
    <another_one>...</another_one>
    <another_one>...</another_one>
  </parent>
</root>
```

In the example the xpath shold select only `<node>` and `<another_one>` because they are appearing more than once.

I was trying to find a solution for this for hours without success (now I think is not possible with XPath...).

Answer (score 7):

**These are impossible to select with a single XPath 1.0 expression** (due to lack of range variables in XPath 1.0).

One possible solution is to select all `/*/*/*` elements, then to get the name of each element, using `name()` off that element, then to evaluate `/*/*/*[name() = $currentName][2]` (where `$currentName` should be substituted with the name just obtained. If the last expression selects an element, then the `currentName` is a name that occurs at least twice -- therefore you keep that element. Do so with all elements and their names. As an auxhiliarry step, one might dedup the names (and selected elements) by placing them in a hash-table.

**In Xpath 2.0 it is trivial to select with a single XPath expression all children of a given parent, that have at least one other sibling with the same name**:

```
/*/*/*
   [name() = following-sibling::*/name()
  and
    not(name() = preceding-sibling::*/name())
   ]
```

**A much more compact expression**:

```
/*/*/*[index-of(/*/*/*/name(), name())[2]]
```

**XSLT 2.0  - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/*/*[index-of(/*/*/*/name(), name())[2]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <node>...</node>
    <node_unique>...</node_unique>
    <node>...</node>
    <another_one>...</another_one>
    <another_one>...</another_one>
  </parent>
</root>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the selected from this evaluation elements are copied to the output**:

```
<node>...</node>
<another_one>...</another_one>
```

**Note**: For a related question/answer, see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287360/36305)**.

Comment: +1, Very expressive and neat answer. But, Sir I thought there might be some other way.

Comment: @Cylian, There always is "some other way" -- we must try to provide the most succinct one, and also a solution that is efficient.

Comment: I really a bit confused why using `/*/*/*`, not just `//*`, but when try to use that with astonishment I found no resultant nodes are selecting. Why this is so? Is `/*/*/*` means anything special?

Comment: @Cylian, `/*/*/*` selects all grand-children of the top element.