# XSLT how to display/output duplicate values based on different element node and attributes

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri, oxygenxml

I am trying to output duplicate values across different nodes and value by using XSLT. I want the node element to be dynamic so it can track different value after the namespace prefix, for example: car:ID, car:Name, car:Location_name, or more. I know i can use the function Local-Name(.) but I am not sure how to apply to my XSLT logic. please help
the sample XML as follow:

```
<car:root xmlns:car="com.sample">
<Car_Input_Request>
    <car:Car_Details>
        <car:ID>Car_001</car:ID>
        <car:Name>Fastmobile</car:Name>
        <car:Local_Name>New York</car:Local_Name>
        <car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
            <car:ID car:type="Transmission_Reference_Type">Automatic</car:ID>
        </car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
    </car:Car_Details>      
</Car_Input_Request>
    <Car_Input_Request>
        <car:Car_Details>
            <car:ID>Car_002</car:ID>
            <car:Name>Slowmobile</car:Name>
            <car:Local_Name>New York</car:Local_Name>
            <car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
                <car:ID car:type="Transmission_Reference_Type">Manual</car:ID>
            </car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
        </car:Car_Details>      
    </Car_Input_Request>
    <Car_Input_Request>
        <car:Car_Details>
            <car:ID>Car_001</car:ID>
            <car:Name>Fastmobile</car:Name>
            <car:Local_Name>New York</car:Local_Name>
            <car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
                <car:ID car:type="Transmission_Reference_Type">Automatic</car:ID>
            </car:Transmission_Reference_Type>
        </car:Car_Details>      
    </Car_Input_Request>
</car:root>
```

The XSLT used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:car="com.sample"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//car:ID[ let $v:=string(.),$t:=@car:type return not( preceding::car:ID[string(.) = $v and @car:type=$t]) ]/(let $v:=string(.), $t:=@car:type,$c:=1+count(following::car:ID[string(.)=$v and $t=@car:type]) ,$c:=1+count(following::car:*[string(.)=$v]) return if ($c > 1) then concat( string(.), ' occurs ', $c, ' times for type ', $t, '&#13;&#10;') else () )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output shown from xslt:

```
Car_001 occurs 2 times for type 
 Automatic occurs 2 times for type Transmission_Reference_Type
```

But I want it to show

```
Car_001 occurs 2 times for type ID
Fastmobile occurs 2 times for type Name
Automatic occurs 2 times for type Transmission_Reference_Type
New York occurs 3 times for type Local_Name
```

Comment: first line ```//car:ID[ let $v:=string(.),$t:=@car:type return not( preceding::car:ID[string(.) = $v and @car:type=$t]) ]``` to finds all car:ID element which do not have dup value. then ```/(let $v:=string(.), $t:=@car:type,$c:=1+count(following::car:ID[string(.)=$v and $t=@car:type]) ,$c:=1+count(following::car:*[string(.)=$v]) return if ($c > 1) then concat( string(.), ' occurs ', $c, ' times for type ', $t, '&#13;&#10;') else () )``` to display the duplicate value if it has count more than 1, and output the variable values such as $t, $c etc.

Comment: For a single XPath expression that finds all duplicate values in a sequence, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133092/how-do-you-identify-duplicate-values-in-a-numerical-sequence-using-xpath-2-0/287360#287360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an XSLT solution (rather than a single line XPath expression), you could make use of `xsl:for-each-group` with a composite key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:car="com.sample"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//car:Car_Details/*" group-by="local-name(), normalize-space()" composite="yes">
        <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
          <xsl:text>{normalize-space()} occurs {count(current-group())} times for {local-name()}&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that works like a charm! Another q, do you know how i can make the for-each-group select dynamic? what if we have a new API request is car:Seller_Details? or car:Buyer_Details... can we do ```select="car:*[....]```?

Comment: You could do `select="//car:*[count(ancestor::car:*) = 1]/*"` to avoid selecting the `car:root` or the children of `car:Car_Details`, for example.